# Cannot use final fields in Room entity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-room, androidx

When using an entity using Room library in java, I want to have few final fields (since i don't want to have setters) and few non-final fields. I have created a similar class called Record, following the official [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity).

```
public class Record {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Id")
    private final long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "CreatedDate")
    private final long createdDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "LastModifiedDate")
    private long lastModifiedDate;

    public Record(long id, long createdDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.lastModifiedDate = createdDate;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public long getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(long unixTime) {
        lastModifiedDate = unixTime;
    }

    public void notifyRecordUpdate() {
        setLastModifiedDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

*Note: I haven't marked this an entity because this is a base class for other entities.*

But, the compiler complains that it cannot find setters for field `id` and `createdDate`.
It gives the following errors:

```
Record.java:10: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final long id;
Record.java:13: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final long createdDate;
```

As per the docs above:

> Constructor does not have to receive all fields as parameters but if a field is not passed into the constructor, it should either be public or have a public setter

the compiler should be able to find the the only constructor for final fields and use the setter for the third non-final field?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue with my code. **Although it's an error made by me**, I think this is such a common design pattern we use everyday in OOPS world  that many might make a similar mistake, hence posting the correct implementation.

Since I was extending the `Record` class, I need to define a constructor in the sub class that takes in all the required parameters.

Here's a small example as to what I was doing (**Incorrect entity implementation**):

```
@Entity(tableName = "Items")
public class Item extends Record {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Something")
    private final String something;

    public Item(@NonNull String something) {
        super(0, System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

This is a valid sub-class and java compiler won't complain, however `room` simply cannot find a valid constructor with all the three required fields `(id, createdDate, something)` which it needs to initialise the object `Item` from the database.

Instead this is how we need to define any subclass.

```
@Entity(tableName = "Items")
public class Item extends Record {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Something")
    private final String something;

    public Item(long id, long createdDate, long @NonNull String something) {
        super(id, createdDate);
        this.something = something;
    }
}
```

This is such a foolish mistake I made that I might be deleting the question altogether in the future if it doen't help anyone.